# How to skip the headers in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Hi I have an excel with the user data in the below format:

```
       User Info                          Order Info                                       
User Name,User Phone Number            Order No,Order Name 
   XYZ,123-123-1234                      123,Test1
   ABC,111-222-1111                      800,Test2
```

How to skip the headers User Info and Order Info in angularjs so that it can start reading from second line which is User Name etc?

```
function userRecord() {
    angular.forEach(vm.readUserData, function (userInfo) {
        userInfo.userName = userInfo['User Name'];
        userInfo.userPhNo = userInfo['User Phone Number'];
    });
}
```

**Output**

```
[{"User Info":"User Name","Order Info":"Order No"},{"User Info":"XYZ","Order Info":"123"}]
```

Comment: show us your code

Comment: //controller.js
function userRecord() {
   angular.forEach(vm.readUserData, function(userInfo){
       userInfo.userName=userInfo['User Name'];                                                
       userInfo.userPhNo=userInfo['User Phone Number'];
                                                                                                                        });
}

Comment: put your code in question section

Comment: and explain what you have done in your code, we are not computer to understand your question automatically

Comment: If you are getting this data in some array, just skip first two lines. are you facing any issue?

Comment: Hi Rakesh above is the code what i tried so far.In my output i see the second headers which is user name,phone number etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using vm.readUserData as an array, and if this array's 1st index contains the header then you can remove these from the array using below javascript function.

```
var newArray = vm.readUserData.shift();
```

Then you can use this array to perform your task.

Comment: Hi Sangram i modified my output that is how i am getting my result.Basically it is reading only the first sub header under the main headers which is user name and order no.How to read the remaining sub headers?